# Update error "Sources disagree on hashes for supposedly identical version"

Tags: server, 18.04, updates

I am running an upgrade/update on Ubuntu server and ran into this.

```
W: Sources disagree on hashes for supposely identical version '0.11.3-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1' of 'python3-httplib2:amd64'.
W: Sources disagree on hashes for supposely identical version '0.11.3-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1' of 'python3-httplib2:amd64'.
```

Should I be concerned about this? Not sure if the source got compromised or if my computer is the cause.

Comment: you have two sources and they disagree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sources you now use have different 'hash' data (a value calculated to show if there's corruption in file sources) so one or more of your packages on one of your sources disagrees with that package on another source.  Solve it by changing sources in /etc/apt/sources.list, following the article at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu .

For an example, you can see bug reports https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1804343 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1373598

If you look at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors you will see the official mirrors you can use to download Ubuntu, packages, and updates from.  Change sources from what you now use, picking one up to date which is reasonably close to you; fast is more important than mileage.

Comment: It was just my PHP7.3 repo conflicting with the main repo.

Comment: This particular conflict is common when adding ondrej's PPA for EOL different PHP-versions. (https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2)